# How to make elasticsearch return all docs which contain certain term without scoring it

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have the following data:

```
{"_index": "simple", "_type": "motorcycle", "_source": {"date": "2018-04-28T10:55", "price": 134900, "sellerName": "Bike MC V\u00e4st AB", "description": "KTM 1290 Super Duke R,Bike G\u00f6teborg M\u00e4tarst\u00e4llning: 498 mil F\u00e4rg: M\u00f6rkbl\u00e5 Typ: Sport Info: M\u00e4rke: KTM 1290 Super Duke R, Bike G\u00f6teborg. F\u00e4rg: Svart. Pris : 134900 kr. \u00c5rsmodell: 2017. M\u00e4tarst\u00e4llning: 498 mil. Senaste service gjordes vid: 498 mil. N\u00e4sta service \u00e4r vid: 1500 mil. Datum f\u00f6r n\u00e4sta besiktning: 2021-04-30. Motoreffekt: 177 HK. Framd\u00e4ck: 60 % kvar, bakd\u00e4ck: 100 % kvar. Utrustning: Arrow slipon inkl original, kraschpuckar, Trackpack. Instruktionsbok, extranyckel medf\u00f6ljer . MC:n har genomg\u00e5tt inbytestest p\u00e5 48 punkter. Nygaranti tom: 2019-04-06. Finansierings ex: 20% kontant = 27059kr, m\u00e5nadsbelopp: 1477kr. MC:n levereras nyservad med nytt bakd\u00e4ck, (KTM 1290 Super Duke R, 1290, sd r, duke, naked, streefighter) Bike G\u00f6teborg 031 3892801", "location": "G\u00f6teborg, Hisingen", "id": 447, "title": "KTM 1290 Super Duke R,Bike G\u00f6teborg", "modelYear": 2017, "url": "https://www.blocket.se/goteborg/KTM_1290_Super_Duke_R_Bike_Goteborg_79076153.htm?ca=11&w=3", "vehicleType": "Sport"}}
{"_index": "simple", "_type": "motorcycle", "_source": {"date": "2018-04-27T16:19", "price": 125000, "sellerName": "Henrik \u00d6rtenwall", "description": "Harley Davidson Night Rod VRSCDX. Fula, breda, l\u00e5nga baksk\u00e4rmen bytt mot en kortare. Utbytta blinkers fram + bak samt baklampa. Nytt rakare, l\u00e4gre, svart styre. M\u00e5nga sm\u00e5 detaljer som bytta fotpinnar, gaffelbensskydd etc. Ca 2800 mil.", "location": "G\u00f6teborg, V\u00e4stra Centrum", "id": 753, "title": "HD Night Rod", "modelYear": 2007, "url": "https://www.blocket.se/goteborg/HD_Night_Rod_79065407.htm?ca=11&w=3", "vehicleType": "Custom"}}
```

Which I'm indexing like this:

```
    def create_index(self, file_path):
        """
            Takes path to file containing JSON-formatted data
            and indexes into Elasticsearch index.
        """
        print('Creating index "{}"'.format(INDEX_NAME))

        request_body = {
"settings":{
    "index":{
        "number_of_shards":1,
        "number_of_replicas":0
    }
},
"mappings":{
    "motorcycle":{
        "properties":{
            "location": {
                "type":"keyword",
            },
            "vehicleType": {
                "type": "keyword",
            },
            "description":{
                "type":"text",
                "analyzer":"swedish",
            },
        }
    }
}
        }
        self.es.indices.create(index = INDEX_NAME, body = request_body)
        f_in = open(PATH_TO_DATASET, "r")
        actions = (json.loads(line) for line in f_in)
        print("Performed bulk index: {}".format(bulk(self.es, actions)))
        self.es.indices.refresh(index = "simple")
```

The data has two documents. Both of them have a location field, which is set to `"G\u00f6teborg, Hisingen"` in the first doc and `"G\u00f6teborg, V\u00e4stra Centrum"` in the second. The `location` field is a keyword field, as you can see in my code. In the beginning, I was using `filter` to filter on the `location` field:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "location": "PlaceName"
                    }
                }
            ]
         }
     }
}
```

However, that required the `PlaceName` to be exactly the same as the `location` field of a document for it to be returned. That's not what I want. **I want any document whose `location` field contains `placeName` to be returned**. So for example, if I specify `G\u00f6teborg` for the location field, both of the documents in my data above should be matched. Also, I don't want this to affect the score of the documents, so that I can simply use it as a filter.

Here's an attempt by me:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{
                "term": {
                    "location": "G\u00f6teborg",
                    "boost":0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query is invalid (returns error message) because of the `boost` field. If I remove `boost`, the query gives no matches, which is also not good.

What is the problem here? How can I achieve the functionality that I want?

EDIT:

This query also returns no results:

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "location":"G\u00f6teborg"
        }
    }
}
```

PS. Changing `G\u00f6teborg` to `Göteborg` gives the same results.

EDIT 2:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "location":{
                "query": "G\u00f6teborg",
                "boost": 0
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This query works in returning all the relevant documents with score 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the type of the `location` field to `text` - the `keyword` type allows only exact matches, however they `text` field will perform [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) using the standard analyzer on the input, and as part of that analysis it performs tokenization which split the text to words so when you query that field you'll also be able to match parts of the content.

In addition to that it's also preferred that you'll change the query type from `term` to `match` since you'll want to have the analyzer applied on the query as well.

Query example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "location": "PlaceName"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see that changing to `text` works, BUT, what about scoring? I will be combining this with queries on other fields, and I want what I'm doing here to ONLY act as a filtering mechanism, returning docs which contain the location specified and not contributing to score at all

Comment: Just apply `filter` on a `match` query like you did with the `term`, it'll work.
The important part here is the field analysis

Comment: Also you should probably use the `swedish` analyzer like you did in the `description` field

Comment: Thanks. I'm having trouble understanding what you mean with applying the `filter` on a `match` query, could you provide an example please? I've tried some different things but I can't quite get it to work.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example.

This will only work if you change your mapping and re-index those documents